# Signature could not be verified setup error

Tags: chirp

What is the possible reason for the "Signature could not be verified" setup error? I'm recompiling an old Ionic/JAVA application that used to work. Thanks

Comment: Are you fetching the Chirp config from the network or using a hardcoded config string?

Comment: I was using hardcoded string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Signature could not be verified" error suggests an invalid configuration string, or perhaps a mismatch between the SDK decryption and the configuration string.

To resolve this issue, I would recommend updating both the ChirpSDK and retrieving a new config string from https://developers.chirp.io